# Searching through start menu ends up with underlined results

Tags: windows-7

I just set up a new Windows 7 computer and must have clicked some box in prefs somewhere by accident. When I hit Start and type into the search box, all of the search results that show up (still in the start menu) are underlined.

This only happens when typing in the start menu, not when I am normally browsing. And it only happens on this machine. Must be some Accessibility issue but I can't figure out where the setting is.

[image: shot]

Can anyone help me turn off the underlining? There's nothing particularly wrong with it, it's just noisy to my eyes, especially when my other Windows 7 machines do not do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow these steps **all** steps:

1. Open **Start Menu**
2. Type in the search box: *Folder Option*
3. Select *Single-Click to open an item (point to select)*

   - Select *Underline icon titles only when I point at them*
4. Select *Double-click to to open an item (single-click to select)*
5. Click **OK**

*Note: You most follow all steps in order.*

<strike>It is not possible. Might be with the help of an 3rd party application. It's the way Windows 7's start menu works.</strike> I stand corrected. I didn't look at the screenshot you posted. My answer has been corrected. It should work now.

Comment: @Scott_Bilas - Off topic... Thank you for what you and your co-workers have done for the industry.

Comment: That was it exactly! I had looked at that dialog but did not notice the grayed out stuff. Somehow the underline option had gotten set. Woo! And also thanks for the kind words, we aim to please. :)

Answer (score 1):

Select "single click to open an item",then click "Underline icon titles only when I point at them",Then click "Double click to open an item." Then you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

No problem.

1. Go to Control Panels > Folder Options
2. In the General tab, either select "Double-click to open an item", or, if you want to use single click, select the second option ("Underline icon titles only when I point at them")
3. Click "Apply" or "Ok"

[image: Folder Options]